# Why is array.forEach() doing nothing in this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to show the results of a search container ordered by distance (comparing the distance between me and the data of each div). Everything works except `resultArray.forEach(...);`.

```
btnSearch.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var inputBuscadorValue = inputBuscador.value;
    var infoDivBuscador = document.getElementsByClassName("div-info"); //a child of a child of mainDiv

    var resultArray = [];

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(infoDivBuscador , function(f){
        if (f.innerHTML.toLowerCase().search(inputBuscadorValue.toLowerCase()) == -1){
            f.parentNode.style.display = "none";
          }else{
            mainDiv.style.display = 'none';

            //It calculates the distance here (it works);                 

             resultArray.push({
               element: f.parentNode,
               distance: d
             });

        });

       resultArray.sort(function(a, b){return a.distance - b.distance});
       console.log(resultArray);

        mainDiv.innerHTML = "";

        resultArray.forEach(function(el) {
          mainDiv.appendChild(el);
          console.log(el); //doesn't log any
        })

        mainDiv.style.display = 'block';

}, false);
```

Comment: Does the `console.log(resultArray);` show you a populated array? If so, can you make a [MCVE]? (edit a live snippet into the question, ideally, or if you can't manage that, link to a JSFiddle or something so that someone else can)

Comment: @CertainPerformance it shows the array with the data reordered.

Comment: If you look at the browser console, the error should be pretty clear: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` (always check your console for errors before asking why things aren't working)

Comment: resultArray is not an array of HTML elements - so `mainDiv.appendChild(el);` won't do anything (except throw an error I suspect) ... did you mean `mainDiv.appendChild(el.element);`

Comment: @CertainPerformance my guess is that reference to the element is broken and hence `f.style...` does not have any impact, but still thats my guess

Comment: yeah, you can't append a js object, only an element.

Comment: Perhaps check your browsers **developer** tools console for errors such as `Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node` (that's the firefox version) - chrome states `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` - at which point after the first iteration, your javascript would stop running

Comment: if you want the results array to be an array of elements, then add this:
resultsArray = resultsArray.map((o) => o.element)
or
resultsArray = resultsArray.map(function (o) { return o.element; });

Comment: Additionally, `resultArray` is created conditionally. If your condition evaluates as false it is never populated.

Comment: @EternalHour - but it's still an array, so it won't FAIL ... there was a comment by the OP that resultArray was not empty ... `it shows the array with the data reordered`

Comment: @CertainPerformance the console doesn't show any error related with that

Comment: @Unaidu - which browser are you using. Have you filtered errors from the console?

Comment: I am extremely doubtful of that - like I said, please post a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem, so we can see for ourselves

Comment: @JaromandaX - I don't see OP mention an error, just that it doesn't work :)

Comment: `mainDiv.appendChild(el);` **will** throw an error, so you're just not looking at the right place

Comment: @EternalHour - looking at the code, the source of an error is obvious - given the comment that the array is populated means that it WILL throw the error (reading between the lines :p )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `mainDiv.appendChild(el)` will cause something like...

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.

because you need to refer to the element in the array in order to append it to the DOM. Also, `resultArray` will only be populated with elements if the `search()` method finds a match. So to me it makes sense to move that block of code inside the condition. Without your html it's impossible to determine exactly how your code is supposed to work, but here is my attempt at a (somewhat) working recreation :)

```js
var btnSearch = document.getElementById("btnSearch");
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
var d = 1;

btnSearch.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var inputBuscadorValue = inputBuscador.value;
  var infoDivBuscador = document.getElementsByClassName("div-info"); //a child of a child of mainDiv

  var resultArray = [];

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(infoDivBuscador, function(f) {
    if (f.innerHTML.toLowerCase().search(inputBuscadorValue.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
      f.parentNode.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      mainDiv.style.display = 'none';

      //It calculates the distance here (it works);                 
      console.log(f);
      resultArray.push({
        element: f.parentNode,
        distance: d
      });

      resultArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.distance - b.distance
      });

      mainDiv.innerHTML = "";

      resultArray.forEach(function(el) {
        mainDiv.appendChild(el.element);
        console.log(el);
      });

      mainDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }

  }, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="searchContainer">
  <input type="text" id="inputBuscador">
  <button type="button" id="btnSearch">
    Search
  </button>
</div>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
<div class="info-parent">
  <div class="div-info">
    <span>Information div 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info-parent">
  <div class="div-info">
    <span>Information div 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info-parent">
  <div class="div-info">
    <span>Information div 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info-parent">
  <div class="div-info">
    <span>Information div 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```